# Replace multi line Text_Element code runs without error but does not replace the text

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, text-element

I am trying to replace a single, 3 line text elements in ArcGIS Pro 2.8.3, with a new, single 3 line text elements. The  existing text looks like this in the layout:

```
NATIONWIDE PERMIT 3  
COD ART RANK PARK TO DEMON BRIDGE  
LA PLATA  COUNTY, COLORADO
```

and the text I want is

```
NATIONWIDE PERMIT 3  
ANIMAS RIVER TRAIL - RANK PARK SEGMENT   
LA PLATA  COUNTY, COLORADO
```

My code does not throw any errors, but it does not change the desired text. I believe it is related to the multiple lines, since the same code works fine for single line text elements. I don't think it is finding the existing text. My code is:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"CURRENT")
for lyt in aprx.listLayouts():
    for elm in lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        if elm.text == "NATIONWIDE PERMIT 3 \n COD ART RANK PARK TO DEMON BRIDGE \n LA PLATA COUNTY, COLORADO":
            elm.text = "NATIONWIDE PERMIT 3 \n ANIMAS RIVER TRAIL - RANK PARK SEGMENT \n LA PLATA COUNTY, COLORADO"
aprx.save()
del aprx
```

I have also tried

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"CURRENT")  
for lyt in aprx.listLayouts(): 
    for elm in lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT"):  
        if elm.text == """NATIONWIDE PERMIT 3
            COD ART RANK PARK TO DEMON BRIDGE
            LA PLATA COUNTY, COLORADO""":
              elm.text = """NATIONWIDE PERMIT 3
                ANIMAS RIVER TRAIL - RANK PARK SEGMENT
                LA PLATA COUNTY, COLORADO"""
aprx.save()
del aprx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first sample of code worked for me. I suspect its because you are putting spaces before and after the newline (\n) character when there is none in your original text element.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I realized that it wasn't finding the text because there was a new line before the first line of text. Once I added a "\n" before the first line of text, and removed the spaces, it worked. Thanks.